# how to render marker on button press in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native, marker

hey guys i am trying to display markers on the map when button is pressed

here is my code

```
getMarkers: function(){
    this.setState({
      return {
        <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.region} image={require('./assets/placeholder-blue.png')} />
      }
    })
},
```

here is my button code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getMarkers}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

but i am facing error while building the app the packager shows unexpected token how can i make this possible? any guide to get this working.

Comment: Include the error it shows in addition to the file it says the error is in.

Comment: Can you please provide your error logs?, for the meantime, check this [Blog](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps). It provides an intuative and react like API declaratively controlling features on the map.

Comment: Your setState is not correct. It is expecting an object to be passed not some return statement. You would do: this.setState({ marker: YOURMARKERCOMPONENT });